# Boost Spirit char parser

Tags: c++, parsing, tuples, character, boost-spirit-qi

Here is a code sample:

```
// file main.cpp

#include <iostream>
#include <boost/tuple/tuple.hpp>
#include <boost/tuple/tuple_io.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>

int main()
{
    std::string s( "1 A" );
    boost::tuple<double, char> p;
    complex_matrix_parser::iterator b = s.begin();
    complex_matrix_parser::iterator e = s.end();
    qi::phrase_parse( b, e,
            ( qi::double_ >> qi::char_('A') ),
            qi::space, qi::skip_flag::postskip, p );

    std::cerr << "==== " << p << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

This should print `==== (1 A)` right? But it prints `==== (1 )`, so it skips the `'A'` character.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `boost::fusion::vector` instead of the `boost::tuple` and everything will work.

Comment: Because `boost::tuple` is not a `boost::fusion` sequence, although it could be adapted into one if you included `boost/fusion/adapted/boost_tuple.hpp`.